# Returning control to cmd.exe after launching an application

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, cmd, batch-file

The use case is as follows:

1. Launch firefox
2. Execute commands in cmd.exe

I need to wrap this in a batch script. But when I launch firefox from the cmd.exe, the cmd.exe has lost the control and the control is returned only after firefox is closed. But I need to perform some operations (step 2) with firefox opened. How can I return control back to cmd.exe once firefox is launched. I know that in linux you can simply use "&" after the command to do so, but I am unaware of any such functionality in windows.

Comment: I tried "c:\firefoxFolder\firefox.exe /k". It seems to work from cmd.exe but not when executed from a batch script.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can solve that using this in your batch file

```
start c:\firefoxFolder\firefox.exe
// issue other commands
```

Comment: If I try "start c:\firefoxFolder\firefox.exe" it launches another cmd.exe window.
If I try "start c:\firefoxFolder\firefox.exe http://abc.com" the webpage is opened in the default browser rather than in firefox.

Comment: I tried "c:\firefoxFolder\firefox.exe /k". It seems to work from cmd.exe but not when executed from a batch scipt

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in your bash script. This means that you need to replace every backslash with two of them.

Comment: @ssn The answer from Harry Johnston is correct one as "start" command considers first parameter in quotes as window title.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
start "Firefox" "c:\program files\firefox folder\firefox.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
start c:\folder\firefox.exe | dir c:\folder
```

Comment: I just get a new cmd.exe window. The browser does not open.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD \program files\mozilla firefox\
firefox
```

Comment: That will wait for Firefox to exit before continuing.